# ¿Por qué cuando hago una petición POST desde una ventana modal se ejecuta varias veces?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estoy trabajando en un CRUD desde Javascript hacia un backend en JAVA con Spring.

El problema se efectúa cuando abro y cierro la ventana modal varias veces antes de realizar en envío de los datos.

Si abro y cierro la ventana 2 veces, y después la abro y envío los datos, se hacen 3 peticiones POST a la base de datos, mientras lo esperado es que solo haga una petición. Ademas, cada petición envía los mismo datos.

Dejo un pequeño vídeo replicando el error:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6XupygchLE

Recargo tantas veces la pagina, porque en la función puse un location.reload(), y es mas rápido en recargar la web de lo que tardan en enviar los datos.

También os dejo el código de esa parte en concreto, aunque no podréis hacer peticiones al backend.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MTG Database</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clear.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Magic The Gathering: Database</h1>
        <div>
            <button id="btn-header-post" class="btn-header">Add Card</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
        <article>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-card" class="modal-hidden">
        <div class="modal-popup">
            <div class="close" id="close-modal-card">+</div>

            <div class="modal-title">
                <p class="modal-id" id="modal-id"></p>
                <p class="modal-name" id="modal-name"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img class="image-card" id="image-card" src="" alt="">
                <blockquote id="modal-quote"></blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-post" class="modal-hidden">
        <div class=" crud-popup">
            <div class="close" id="close-modal-post">+</div>
            <div class="modal-title">
                <p class="modal-name">Add card</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" id="add-name-card" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" id="add-img-card" placeholder="URL Image">
                <input type="text" id="add-quote-card" placeholder="Quote">
                <br>
                <button id="btn-post" class="btn-header">Add Card</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```javascript
const showAllCards = (res) => {
    /*
    * Este metodo carga toda las cartas en la rejilla central
    */
    let article = document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0];

    for (line in res) {
        let section = document.createElement('section');
        section.id = res[line].id;

        ids.push(parseInt(res[line].id));

        let paragraph = document.createElement('p');

        let id_card = document.createElement('span');
        id_card.classList.add('id-card');
        id_card.innerHTML = '#' + res[line].name;

        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = res[line].image;
        img.classList.add('image-card');

        paragraph.appendChild(id_card);
        paragraph.classList.add('name-card');
        paragraph.textContent = res[line].name;

        section.appendChild(paragraph);
        section.appendChild(img);

        article.appendChild(section);
    }
}

const showCard = (res) => {
    /*
    * Este metodo carga una carta en una ventana modal
    */
    let modal_card = document.getElementById('modal-card');
    let id = document.getElementById('modal-id');
    let name = document.getElementById('modal-name');
    let image = document.getElementById('image-card');
    let quote = document.getElementById('modal-quote')
    let close = document.getElementById('close-modal-card')

    id.textContent = '#' + res.id;
    name.textContent = res.name;
    image.src = res.image;
    quote.textContent = res.quote;

    modal_card.setAttribute('class', 'modal-background');

    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let modal_card = document.getElementById('modal-card');

        modal_card.setAttribute('class', 'modal-hidden');
    })
}

const postCard = () => {
/*

/!\ FUNCION QUE ME DA EL PROBLEMA

*/
    // Mostrar la ventana modal
    let modal_post = document.getElementById('modal-post');
    modal_post.setAttribute('class', 'modal-background');


    let btn_post = document.getElementById('btn-post');
    let close = document.getElementById('close-modal-post')

    // Extraer datos del formulario 
    let name_card = document.getElementById('add-name-card');
    let img_card = document.getElementById('add-img-card');
    let quote_card = document.getElementById('add-quote-card');

    //Cuando se envien los datos
    btn_post.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            name: name_card.value,
            quote: quote_card.value,
            image: img_card.value
        };

        // Peticion POST de una las cartas
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/mtgdb/card', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.ok ? Promise.resolve(res) : Promise.reject(res))

        location.reload();

    }, true)

    //Cerrar ventana
    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal_post.setAttribute('class', 'modal-hidden');
        name_card.value = "";
        img_card.value = "";
        quote_card.value = "";

        console.log('cerrando ventana')

    }, true)
}


window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let article = document.getElementsByTagName('article')[0];
    let btn_header_post = document.getElementById('btn-header-post');
    let btn_put = document.getElementById('btn-header-put');
    let btn_delete = document.getElementById('btn-header-delete');

    // Peticion GET de todas las cartas
    fetch('http://localhost:8081/mtgdb/card')
        .then(res => res.ok ? Promise.resolve(res) : Promise.reject(res))
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => showAllCards(res))
        .catch(error => alert('prueba'));

    // Peticion GET de una sola carta
    article.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        url = 'http://localhost:8081/mtgdb/card/' + event.target.parentNode.id
        console.log(event.target.parentNode.id)
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.ok ? Promise.resolve(res) : Promise.reject(res))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => showCard(res))
    })

    btn_header_post.addEventListener('click', () => postCard());
})
```

El CSS no creo que sea relevante para solucionar el problema.

He intentado varias cosas:

- Hacer el `fetch` en una función externa
- Cambiar donde declaro `data` y su scope
- Cambiar el tipo de evento
- He reescrito la función completa un par de veces
- Hacer un `delete` de los objetos del DOM en el evento de cerrar la ventana modal

No tengo ni idea donde se esta produciendo el fallo exactamente, y lo mas importante, es que no tengo ni idea de porque se esta produciendo.

Quiero entender que estoy haciendo mal, y como puedo evitarlo.

¡Un saludo a todos!